# Cabal Install failing to install cabal-install

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

Just installed the Haskell platform. When I do

```
$ cabal install cabal cabal-install
```

I get

```
Build log ( /Users/robbiecarlton/.cabal/logs/cabal-install-1.22.6.0.log ):
Configuring cabal-install-1.22.6.0...
Building cabal-install-1.22.6.0...
Preprocessing executable 'cabal' for cabal-install-1.22.6.0...
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id HTTP-4000.2.10-da371776b88c2889959897a2dc40abe7
(use -v for more information)
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cabal-install-1.22.6.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

The same thing happens trying to install manually from source.

Comment: Have you tried manually installing HTTP?

Comment: I'm not sure you should use cabal-install 1.22.x with the ghc version coming with the platform anyway

Comment: What version of the Haskell Platform are you using?